# Source code of the color ramp node

Tags: node-editor

I'm not savy with browsing Blenders source code. For another purpose I'm interested in the source code of the color ramp node.

Not the UI stuff of it, just the "math" behind it, the "take in everything, from a single number up to a complete bitmap, and remap those values according to the sliders count, color and position".

Anyone that's into Blenders source code can help me out and post the code of the color ramp node? Or maybe directions so I can find it myself?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Blender's source code.

Comment: If you're using Gnu/Linux or some other Unix version, you can just use the command grep. For instance, `grep -r 'colorRamp' .`. In windows [there's findstr](http://superuser.com/a/300820/539265)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you're looking for is [here](https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/blob/HEAD:/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/texture.c) on line 322 (the `do_colorband` function).

[This](https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/blob/HEAD:/source/blender/compositor/nodes/COM_ColorRampNode.cpp) is the definition of the node itself, and the operation is implemented [here](https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/blob/HEAD:/source/blender/compositor/operations/COM_ColorRampOperation.cpp): apparently it samples a colourband texture using the input as texture coordinates.

Comment: unfortunately these links have partially rotted.